# Node.JS white listing mobile apps?

Tags: node.js, authentication, mobile

I'm building a node.js application which serves publicly accessible https APIs.

Having said that, I want to build a middleware which should tell me the device type(android/ios/windows/web -> already done).

And if it's a mobile app accessing the APIs, I need to know app bundle ID as well e.g. ***com.awesome-app.app*** -> **how to do this?**

My goal here is to whitelist certain web apps and some mobile apps only.

**So, is there any way I can find out mobile app's `bundle ID` like the way we can find out a website's `origin` in request headers?**

Please let me know if there are other ways available to accomplish this instead of a middleware?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use of middlewares is the good option. I don't think there are any other ways to restrict or allow users. Using middleware is only and best way so far.

Comment: Agree. But how would you identify which mobile application is accessing your public API?

Comment: You can send app specific key in headers say **app-key** and check them in middleware and allow which you want to allow.

Comment: Yes. I can always do that but as a last resort! It would be great if somehow a middleware could tell me the bundle ID of the application. Like the way we can find out `origin` in the request headers.

Comment: Ok, I think you wait for sometime to see if you get any other response. But I know there is no other better way. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking about your Node.js app so middleware seems to be the solution. 
But you can use other services such as Apigee to filter requests.

If you don't have any authentication middleware, any app can fake the request to your app so any solution won't be good enough.